# Achievements screen in iOS app doesn't show Area 51 icon

Tags: bug, badges, area-51, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Today I received the [Enthusiast badge](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/enthusiast?userid=151554) on Area 51 (or rather, the *discussion* part of the site). This shows up in my Achievements list in the iOS app, but the icon is missing:

[image]

This is how it looks like on the website, where the icon *is* shown:

[image]

It's also missing in the Feed:

[image]

Specifications:

- iPhone 7 Plus
- iOS 10.2.1
- App version 1.6.3.6